# Regex to check a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to check a string and then extract all the variables which starts with `@`. I can't find the appropriate regular expression to check the string. The string may start with `@` or `"` and if it's started with `"` it should have a matching pair `"`.

Example 1:

```
"ip : "+@value1+"."+@value2+"."+@value3+"."+@value4
```

Example 2:

```
@nameParameter "@yahoo.com"
```

Thanks

Comment: this is kind of unclear - what are you trying to extract? for each of your examples, you should list what you want in your results array.

Comment: I think he wants all the @'s except when inside a quoted string.

Comment: Whenever you start looking for "matching pairs", you might want to starting thinking about something other than a regex.  Not that it will be impossible to make the expression work; just that it will likely end up as more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: yes Adam is right those after @'s are my parameters and those in double quote (") pairs are the fixed values .

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easiest to first split the string on each quoted string, then check the unquoted parts for @'s.  For example all quoted strings could be: `/"[^"]*"/`, calling Regex.Split on your string would return an array of strings of the non-quoted parts, which you could then use the expression `/@\w+/` to find any @'s.

Comment: I tried to split the string with /"[^"]*"/ but it didn't work !!!

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"/""[^""]*/""");
            string[] consts = reg.Split(valueToCheck);

Comment: that was a syntax error I should have changed something .but thank you about the split suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string text = "@nameParameter \"@yahoo.com\"";
Regex variables = new Regex(@"(?<!"")@\w+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (Match match in variables.Matches(text))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the strings you have provided in your post:

(^("[^"\r\n]*"\s*+@[\w.]+\s*+?)+)|(((^@[\w.]+)|("@[\w.]+"))\s*)+